# Best practices for SQL JOIN ON IF Field1 IS NULL then Field2 ELSE Field1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 decent size tables (200k+ rows) that I'm trying to do a basic left join on.  There are 2 different ID fields in each table that can be used for joining

ID1 = better to join on but often NULL, alphanumeric so it's a varchar

ID2 = always has a value, numeric

So I'm currently JOINING like this, but after 10 mins or so I'm canceling it:

```
SELECT a.*,
       b.fieldname
FROM TABLE1 a
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b
     ON COALESCE(a.ID1,CONVERT(Varchar(10),a.ID2)) = COALESCE(b.ID1,CONVERT(Varchar(10),b.ID2))
```

I basically prefer to JOIN ON ID1, but when ID1 is NULL, then JOIN ON ID2

Is there a more efficient way to do this?  Help appreciated

**** UPDATE

Think of if the data looked like this in both tables:

```
ID2              ID1
300              NULL
301              NULL
309              NULL
311              311-A
311              311-B
314              NULL
316              316-1
316              316-3
```

So as you can see most of the time ID1 is NULL and that's fine because ID2 is unique, but sometimes there is extensions of ID2, and thats when I want to join on ID1

So what I'd be trying to achieve is something like this in psuedocode:

```
SELECT a.*,
    b.fieldname
FROM TABLE1 a
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b
  ON IF a.ID1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
           a.ID1 = b.ID1
       ELSE
           a.ID2 = b.ID2
    END
```

Comment: You're going to have a lot of trouble with this because you're doing pretty considerable Conversions on 200,000 rows of data.  What are you trying to accomplish with the COALESCE?  Could you achieve the same result by adding a `WHERE TABLE2.ID IS NULL`?  It would stop you from running COALESCE on 200,000 rows.  It may even reduce the number of conversions you have to do.

Comment: *`WHERE TABLE2.ID IS NULL` or something comparable, depending on your case.

Comment: You might want to rethink your table structure if possible.  If not, then you would probably have a better performance using 2 queries with `union` separating your `on` criteria for both.  Also make sure you have the appropriate indices on your tables, both for `id1` and `id2`.

Comment: Why don't you always use ID2? Numeric values are better and you should use INDEX on any table that appears in WHERE.

Comment: ID1 is a further extension of ID2.  In most cases ID1 is NULL and ID2 is unique so joining on that is easy.  However, in the examples where ID2 is not unique, there is a unique value in ID1 for it.  So basically what I'm trying to achieve is like a CASE, or IF statement in my JOIN ON clause.  So table1 JOIN table2 ON IF ID1 IS NULL ID2 ELSE ID1.  I'm not sure how else to explain it.  A UNION would certainly work in this example as I've tried that in the past but not with this particular JOIN.  I'll give that a shot.  I thought there might just be a simplier way (less code) to do it, thanks!

Comment: I added an updated section above in the original example, with a sample set of data.  Perhaps I was confusing.  Hopefully above makes more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an ON clause of:

`ON (a.ID1 IS NOT NULL AND a.ID1=b.ID1) OR (a.ID1 IS NULL AND a.ID2=b.ID2)`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to the above problem...
Couple of them are as below

- You can start to redesign the table structures to better get a unique
  id --> This is often said but hard to do.
- Create a computed column in your table itself (let us call ID3),
  which will store the ID1 value if it is not null, or else stores
  ID2 value --> This approach will increase your table space, and
  also will impact your write speeds. If you are not so concerned
  about the write performance and only concerned above read
  performance this approach is better suited.
- you can also use the approach of you asked for a query where can check if ID1 is null or not, it will be written as below

  `SELECT a.*,b.fieldname
  FROM TABLE1 a
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b
  ON   (
          ( a.ID1 IS NOT NULL AND a.ID1 = b.ID1 )
          OR
          ( a.ID1 IS NULL AND a.ID2 = b.ID2 )
       )`

Comment: Yes thank you your join worked great, and I appreciate your feedback in the other areas